# Display MQTT data on web application using Socket.io

Tags: html, node.js, socket.io, mqtt

```
 var socket = io.connect();
         socket.on('connect', function () {
             socket.on('mqtt', function (msg) {
                 var message = msg.topic.split('/');
                 var area = message[1];
                 var state = message[2];
                 console.log(msg.topic, msg.payload);
                 var timestamp = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
                 $('#topic').html(msg.topic);
                 $('#message').html(msg.topic + ', ' + msg.payload);
                 switch (area) {
                     case 'living':
                         $('#value1').html('(Sensor value: ' + msg.payload + ')');
                         $('#label1').text(msg.payload + '°C');
                         $('#label1').removeClass('').addClass('label-default');
                         var entry = new Array();
                         entry.push(timestamp);
                         entry.push(parseInt(msg.payload));
                         Temperature.push(entry);
                         // Show only 20 values
                         if (Temperature.length >= 20) {
                             Temperature.shift()
                         }
```

Please I am trying to display my MQTT data on my web app and it seems not to update anytime i receive a message

```
var cfenv = require('cfenv');
var app = express();
var http=require('http');
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io  = require('socket.io')(server);
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var MQTT_TOPIC          = "IOC/Ke/Data";
var MQTT_ADDR           = "mqtt://realtime.ngi.ibm.com";
var MQTT_PORT           = 1883;

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

//connect to mqtt server
var client  = mqtt.connect(MQTT_ADDR,{clientId:'abbanodejs',protocolId:'MQIsdp', protocolVersion:3,connectTimeout:30*1000, debug:true});

//Connect to mqtt topic
client.on('connect', function () {
io.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on('subscribe', function(data){
console.log('Subscribing to '+data.topic);
socket.join(data.topic);
client.subscribe(data.topic);
client.publish(MQTT_TOPIC, 'Hello mqtt');
});
});
});

// listen to messages coming from the mqtt broker
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
console.log(topic+'='+message);
io.emit('mqtt',
{'topic':topic,
  'payload':message
}
);
});
```

That is my server code on the other side, it works properly and gives me my desired output

Comment: what is the error on your firebug browser ?

Comment: there is no error,the html runs fine but it doesn't update the values into the html element

Comment: What's on the other end of the socket.io connection?